# Python regex to replace URLs in text with links (conversion from PHP)

Tags: python, regex

Could someone convert this PHP regex to Python? I tried it for several times with no success:

```
function convertLinks($text) {
    return preg_replace("/(?:(http:\/\/)|(www\.))(\S+\b\/?)([[:punct:]]*)(\s|$)/i",
    "<a href=\"http://$2$3\" rel=\"nofollow\">$1$2$3</a>$4$5", $text);
}
```

---

Edit:
I found that [:punct:] can be replaced by [!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~], so I tried this:

```
def convertLinks(text):
    pat = re.compile(ur"""(?:(http://)|(www\.))(\S+\b\/?)([!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~]*)(\s|$)""", re.IGNORECASE)
    return pat.sub(ur'<a href=\"http://\2\3" rel=\"nofollow\">\1\2\3</a>\4\5', text)
```

but I received "unmatched group" error for convertLinks(u"Test www.example.com test").

Comment: Note that you *should* have included (some of) your efforts in your post, that way you (a) would have shown that you put in effort yourself and (b) would have given us a better starting point in helping you.

Comment: Some example input cases with desired output would have been very helpful too.

Comment: OK, I will do it this way next time, thanks.

Comment: You can still *add* that info to your question, and have it reopened. As it stands now, your question will be auto-deleted after some time, because it has a negative score. If more of your questions follow the same pattern in the future, you run the risk of being banned from asking further questions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added my original solution attempt. How can I reopen the quesion or it will be done autmatically?

Comment: Because you edited it, yes, it'll automatically be added to the re-open review queue. That is a *review* queue, so others have to vote on  your post now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression uses some features that work differently in Python.

- Python doesn't have a `[[:punct:]]` character group; I used a [POSIX regex reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) to expand it.
- The expression uses optional groups; matching either `http://` *or* `www.` at the start, but then uses *both* in the replacement. This will fail in Python. Solution: use a replacement function.

So to get the same functionality, you can use:

```
import re

_link = re.compile(r'(?:(http://)|(www\.))(\S+\b/?)([!"#$%&\'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~]*)(\s|$)', re.I)

def convertLinks(text): 
    def replace(match):
        groups = match.groups()
        protocol = groups[0] or ''  # may be None
        www_lead = groups[1] or ''  # may be None
        return '<a href="http://{1}{2}" rel="nofollow">{0}{1}{2}</a>{3}{4}'.format(
            protocol, www_lead, *groups[2:])
    return _link.sub(replace, text)
```

Demo:

```
>>> test = 'Some text with www.stackoverflow.com links in them like http://this.too/with/path?'
>>> convertLinks(test)
'Some text with <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" rel="nofollow">www.stackoverflow.com</a> links in them like <a href="http://this.too/with/path" rel="nofollow">http://this.too/with/path</a>?'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex in python, you should consider using the [`re`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module. In this example, specifically [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub).

The syntax is something similar to:

```
output = re.sub(regular_expression, what_it_should_be_replaced_by, input)
```

Don't forget that `re.sub()` returns the substituted string.

Comment: Thnaks, but I know it of course. What I need is a help with the conversion from PHP regex form to Python regex form. I do not ask for the function or module I should use.

Comment: Sorry, but I wrote in my post I tried it several times. I use re.sub() but as I wrote, I have troubles with converting the regular expression.

Comment: *what part* is troubling you? I do note that I can see where there might be difficulties, this regular expression is a little more verbose. It has references in the replacement part that *may not exist* which does throw Python.

Comment: Martijn, thanks for your help. I did the modification similar to yours ones, but I received "unmatched group" error (which I unfortunatelly received also using your code)

Comment: @sthr: Updated, that is the part I talked about.